# Get output on screen from linux command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I tried to get command output in a command but I could't get it. If I run manually, It return normal result in screen.

> `[root@mymachine ~]# dnsdist -e "topQueries()"
>   1  Rest                                        0 100.0%`

I tried with `dnsdist -e 'topQueries() 2>&1 1> /tmp/abc`. But `/tmp/abc` still was empty.
I don't think `screen` command can resolve it. 
Does anyone have any recommendations?

Addition information:

> 1   Rest                                        0 100.0%

is the result from topQueries(). '-e' mean execute a command in dnsdist. It works look like we access mysql then we call a sql statement.

Comment: and result is printed on screen ?

Comment: Yes. As my example, After I run command manually, I see this result in screen.

Comment: Order of redirection is important, how about `examplecommand > /tmp/abc 2>&1`

Comment: If you want it, i will send. This command come from dnsdist rpm (version 1.1 beta). Command: dnsdist -e 'makeKey()'

Comment: I tried with your way, both /tmp/abc and screen are empty.

Comment: run `strace -f examplecommand` you will find which file handle/os method is used to output.

Comment: I copy a part of it. I'm not familiar with `strace`command

Comment: `mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7c24d1b000`


`write(1, "setKey(\"oMwbWGGJwrm5eTWmVp2JXD07"..., 55setKey("oMwbWGGJwrm5eTWmVp2JXD07VcHvUikYsNUlpCHm66w=")
) = 55`


`close(4)`

Comment: The result in output command is setKey("oMwbWGGJwrm5eTWmVp2JXD07VcHvUikYsNUlpCHm66w=")

Comment: Are you sure you are running bash and not some other exotic shell? Are you also sure that you can write on `/tmp/abc` (not a directory, enough space on partition...)?

Comment: Yes. Everything is normal. I have basic experience with Linux.  I don't know how i can get this output. It doesn't like normal command.

Comment: Your best hope of getting an answer is to run the `strace` command again, and click `edit` under your post and paste a fuller version of the output...

Comment: I eddited. Full strace is very long

Answer (score 1):

As [rkosegi commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959987/get-output-on-screen-from-linux-command#comment69129374_40959987), order is important. When you run:

```
examplecommand 2>&1 1> /tmp/abc
```

It takes the stderr output and sends it to *where stdout is currently going* and then sends stdout to the file.

You may want, instead:

```
examplecommand 1> /tmp/abc 2>&1
```

which sends stdout to the file, then sends stderr to *where stdout is currently going*, namely the file.

Comment: It's not work :( Both /tmp/abc and screen still empty value.

Comment: Seem I could not get this result from both stdout and stderr

Comment: You just missed a `>` there.

Answer (score 0):

> To have stderr and stdout both to te screen and in a file /tmp/abc you
>   can use tee.

```
$cat a.sh
echo "stderr" >&2
echo "stdout"

./a.sh 2>&1 | tee /tmp/abc
stderr
stdout

$ cat /tmp/abc
stderr
stdout
```